# Evento ao fechar aba/navegador

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Bom galera blz, queria saber como faço para chamar um evento quando fecho aba ou navegador e quando fechar queria que fizesse um update no mysql ex: logado=1, ai quando fecha faz update para logado=0

Comment: Por que não usar o `SESSION` do PHP?

Comment: Como faria para quando fechar a aba ou navegador destruir a session ?

Comment: Pode usar [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) com javascipt, embora não funcione em 100% das situações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia usar um `beforeunload` para chamar teu evento antes que a janela feche, apesar de não ser compatível com alguns navegadores.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
    //meu evento
});
```

Uma solução alternativa, seria enviar em periodos de tempo constantes um POST avisando ao server que o user ainda está online, como por exemplo:

```
var online = setInterval(function (){
    //fazer teu post aqui
}, 60000);
```

Assim a cada 60 segundos o usuário será atualizado com o horário atual, depois para verificar se ele está online ou não basta verificar se a última vez em que foi visto já tem mais de 60 segundos.

Comment: Obrigado amigo me ajudou bastante.